# AWS Code Deploy - Non compressed files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I am currently using AWS CodeDeploy to deploy some apps via an S3 bucket. Unfortunately I have to zip/tar my app and upload in order for CodeDeploy to deploy it.

Is there a way for CodeDeploy to deploy from an S3 folder rather than a zip/tar file? I realise this is possible from GitHub, however I have a private GIT Repo which isn't supported by CodeDeploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the below AWS Code Deploy push command?

> aws deploy push --application-name HelloWorld_App --s3-location s3://codedeploydemobucket/HelloWorld_App.zip --ignore-hidden-files

You could easily create your own tool / wrapper using the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK for your preferred language that takes in a s3 folder and downloads the file and pushes it to code deploy.

However if you are trying to integrate it into your CI pipeline in Jenkins then you should able to use this plugin.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWS+Codedeploy+plugin

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using the AWS GUI for Code Deploy. Not the AWS CLI. It looks like this isn't possible. I guess I will have to back to Jenkins for deployments. I think CodeDeploy is just too immature.

Comment: You have to incorporate code deploy as part of your jenkins CI pipeline.

Comment: How does that solve the problem with archived files?

Comment: With Jenkins I'm assuming you have stages / steps where you build , package and then deploy. Instead of sending your files directly s3 you need to use something like the AWS CLI and the aws deploy push command which will Archive the files and push it to a s3 location.

Comment: This might be useful - https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/aws-codedeploy-jenkins-plugin-now-available-including-devcloud

Comment: Thanks, looks like I will use that plugin. Probably the only option.

Comment: I've updated the answer and best of luck. Don't forget to mark as answer if you are happy with the answer.